# Pulling common IDs using sql query

Tags: sql

table name : Account

Column :

```
ParentID      RecordType
ABC100        X
ABC100        Y
EFG100        x
HIJ200        x
JKL200        Y
UVW100        Y
UVW100        X
```

how can i pull ParentID ABC100 and UVW100? i want to pull only those parentids where i have both X and Y as record type?

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation.  If you have no duplicates:

```
select parentid
from t
where recordtype in ('X', 'Y')
group by parentid
having count(*) = 2;
```

Or, if you have duplicates in the table:

```
having min(recordtype) <> max(recordtype)
```

Answer (score 0):

If table size is not huge and size of inner query will not exeed 2100 you can use inner query.

```
SELECT parentId 
FROM Account 
WHERE recordType = 'X' 
AND parentId IN 
(SELECT parentId FROM Account WHERE recordType = 'Y')
```

Comment: What does that mean? *size of inner query will not exeed 2100*

Comment: count of rows that will be selected by query in brackets: count of rows with recordType='Y'

Comment: Well, this will also work with millions of rows returned. Maybe you confused it with a limit regarding the maimum number of hard-coded values in an IN-list? Some DBMSes might have such a limit.

Comment: Yes, it is not a problem for raw sql, but it is a problems when this t-sql is used in applications sometimes((

Comment: what if i have value Z also in record type. can i just add another subquery with OR condition? something like:   SELECT parentId 
FROM Account 
WHERE recordType = 'X' 
AND parentId IN 
(SELECT parentId FROM Account WHERE recordType = 'Y') OR (SELECT parentId FROM Account WHERE recordType = 'Z')

Comment: if you need all the 3 conditions together - you shoud add third query using AND. If you use OR the it will select pairs (X,Z), (Y,Z). Also after AND|OR you should also add "parentId IN" in your query

Answer (score 0):

Just to round out your options, you could also use a combination of `WHERE` and `WHERE EXISTS`.

```
select
 ParentID
from 
  account as o
where
  RecordType = 'X'
  and
  exists (select 1
          from account as i 
          where 
            i.ParentID = o.ParentID
            and
            i.RecordType = 'Y'
          );
```